# How to run a command if total internet data egress hits a threshold?

Tags: linux, networking

There are [many tools](https://www.tecmint.com/linux-network-bandwidth-monitoring-tools/) to monitor egress *rate*, but I haven't been able to find one that provides a single number for the total bandwidth, ideally in an easy to consume way, like:

```
tip eth0 egress -t 100GB -c 'sudo shutdown now'
```

Which is basically what I want to do: trigger a command (like shutting down the VPS) when the data exceeds some limit.

Because usage is spiky in my case, it doesn't work to use one of the above tools, nor `tc` to limit the *rate*. Rather I need to limit the *total*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around and wrote you a script which will measure your usage, and execute a command.  It takes the bytes from the interface, adds them together, converts them to gigabytes (note I used 1024 rather then 1000 for my divisions - you can adjust to make it more sensitive...)

Save the below script, make it executable (ie chmod +700 /path/to/script.name if it should be executable only by root), then add to Crontab.

```
#! /bin/bash
INTERFACE=br0

# Limit in Gigabytes
LIMIT=100

bytesin=$( cat /sys/class/net/${INTERFACE}/statistics/tx_bytes )
bytesout=$( cat /sys/class/net/${INTERFACE}/statistics/rx_bytes )
gbtotal=$((( $bytesin + $bytesout )/1024/1024/1024))

   if [ $gbtotal -gt $LIMIT ]
then
    echo "Execute this command"
fi
```

You can add this to crontab multiple ways. One is to add the following to /etc/crontab

```
* * * * *   root /path/to/script.name
```

Some notes about my script:

1. Script is quick and dirty and hardly tested - you got what you paid for.
2. It assumes that the action you take is going to cause the interface to reset its byte counters - eg power off.
3. It is not entirely accurate - specifically it will only run once a minute from cron.
4. I've not tried it, but downing the interface and bringing it back up again should in theory reset the counters.
5. Use at your own risk.  It is conceivable that it will cause a boot loop if I've done something wrong and you execute a shutdown/restart.